# How do you solve this nonhomogeneous recurrence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Im having some troubles with solving the following nonhomogeneous recurrence, i will only post the non-homogenous part of the recurrence as that is the part i dont understand:  **$4^n * \cos(\pi*n)$**,

The homogenous part of the recurrence is **$A*(-4)^n$**

Now i did some solving myself and got to the following form for the particual part of the recurrence and was wondering if it is correct or not.

**$ 4^n*( B*\sin(\pi n) + C*\cos(\pi n))$**

**Edit** Adding Whole equation

**$a_{n+1} + 4a_n = 4^n * cos(\pi n)$**

Comment: Notice that $$4^n\cos{(\pi n)}=(-4)^n$$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z} $. So the particular solution is $Cn(-4)^n$

Comment: it will be better you post the whole equation.

Comment: editet my post with the full equation

Comment: @PeterForeman could you explain that please?

Comment: What is $\sin(\pi n)$ ?

Comment: Your answer is neither correct nor incorrect, it is unfinished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't afraid of complex numbers, you see that you can write your recurrence as:

$\begin{align*}
a_{n + 1} + 4 a_n
  &= \frac{\exp(n \pi i) + \exp(-n \pi i)}{2}
\end{align*}$

The forcing function is now a sum of powers, and the solution routine. Translate back into trigonometric functions at the end.